# Unable to get login page in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I am unable to get a Login page after Moodle 2.5 installation got over. it throws following error

The page isn't redirecting properly 
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

I will be more helpful if anybody gives me an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a fresh install?

I would first check this setting is correct in config.php - something like

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://localhost/yourwebname';
```

or

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://www.yourdomainname.com';
```

If those are correct then clear the cookies in the browser for the specific domain.

And maybe clear the Moodle cache. From a terminal, go to your web directory

```
cd /var/www/moodle
```

Then run

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Administration_via_command_line#Purge_caches_via_CLI

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To give you more details, I am using WAMP server 2.2, Apache 2.2.1, mySQL 5.5.20, pHp 5.3.10.

Comment: I have checked all mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I am unable to run the last line "purge_caches.php".

Comment: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Please let me know any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ah.. I don't know WAMP - it looks like the error message isn't specific to Moodle, you might want to add the tags WAMP, XAMPP and Firefox to the question - it might be a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue (except with XAMMP, and Moodle 2.7, but my guess is the same issues are at play). The solution at https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=239793#p1115879 worked for me.

Basically, delete the contents of moodledata\cache (just use explorer, no need for any CLI stuff), and increase max memory in php.ini (should be wamp\php\php.ini) from 128M to 1024M, then try loading the page again.